# Website is a mirror. How to detect this programmatically in php?

Tags: php, mirror

For example I have 4g-market.ru But it is a mirror for peterhost.ru. How I can detect this programmatically?

Comment: You may need to be more specific. E.g. if you know both web sites then you could use a diff tool to compare. If you need a tool that discovers a duplicated web site you are probably up for a slightly larger task ...

Comment: I visited the first site, and it throws me directly to the second site. It's a PHP redirect (or an HTML one, I'll check).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function detects only a single-bounce redirect (`site1 -> site2`, not `site1 -> site3 -> site2`):

```
function isRedirect($url)
{
  $headers = get_headers($url, true);

  $status = $headers[0];
  list($protocol, $code, $message) = split(' ', $status, 3);

  return ($code >= 300 && $code < 400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might find this paper useful http://www2007.org/papers/paper194.pdf it is about similar website and different URL. It take some heuristic approach to analysing a specific web url and predicting it similarity.